# Class inheritance order for a simulation program

Tags: python, inheritance

This is a somewhat basic question about the correct order of class inheritance.
Basically I'm trying to write a numerical simulation to solve a physical model, the details are not important (I happen to be writing this in python), it is a well known algorithm solved by iterating over a volume of space.

The classes that I think I need are:

- **Setup**: A class that defines all of the simulation parameters, like volume size, and has methods for checking for correct parameter type, calculating derived parameters etc.
- **Solver:** Contains the actual algorithm for solving
- **Output:** Contains handles for all the plot output and has access to save file etc.

I also need a run method which can run the solver and periodically (with periods defined in Setup) run some of the output functions.

1. In a high quality program which class would inherit from which? (My guess Output inherits from Solver inherits from Setup)
2. Where does the run method belong? Maybe there should be some extra base class like Interface that the user interacts with and includes the run method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a concept that encourages the use of composition over inheritance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) so I would say that if you really don't need inheritance don't use it (they can be independent objects or functions, which in python are like objects).
2. If you model this with objects, run() should be in #Solver. Recall that the concept of interface is not necessary in python like in other languages, so you can either use objects, or functions with the algorithms you need.

Comment: Thank you for that, I think I will go for composition having read some articles. I agree with Antimony that inheritance is not really needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you coming from a Java background by any chance?

First off, you've given no indication that any of your classes should inherit from another. For that matter, you probably don't need as many classes as you think you do.

> Solver #Contains the actual algorithm for solving

If it's only one function you might as well just leave it as a free function.

> Output #Contains handles for all the plot output and has access to save file etc.

If the functions don't have shared state, it could just as easily be a module.

As for the run method, just stick it wherever it is most convenient. The nice thing about Python is that you can start prototyping without any classes, and just refactor into a class whenever you find yourself passing the same set of data around a lot.